# How to use mapreduce to count the same values in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am new to MongoDB and am trying to learn how to use mapreduce to count entries with the same value. Here is my example schema I am trying to learn from:

```
{
    "id" : ObjectId("5913et2s059f950g9b799867"),
    "name" : "Sam’s Hotdog Stand",
    "country" : "USA",
    "location:" {
        "longitude" : 104.9903,
        "latitude" : 39.7392
    }
}
```

I am trying to count the number of restaurants with the same longitude (truncating the decimal).

I have my map function:

```
map = function() {
    emit({
        longitude: Math.floor(this.location.longitude),
        name: this.components.name
    }, {
        count : 1
    });
}
```

but am a little lost on the reduce part. I know I need to compare each value, but am confused on how to do it. This is what I have so far, I understand how to count each value, but not check if the longitudes are the same:

```
reduce = function(key, values) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        total += values[i].count;
    }
    return { count : total };
}
```

How do I count each restaurant with the same longitude, and how do I separate them to each longitude?

Comment: Do you really need map/reduce? Today this task is much more easily accomplished with the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @D.SM, while it probably would be easier, this is the practice question I have for mapreduce. Is it possible to do with mapreduce?

Comment: Try omitting the `name` from the key.